# Add log4net Level field to logstash.conf file

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to add LEVEL field (so it shows up in Kibana). My logstash.conf

Input:

```
2018-03-18 15:43:40.7914 - INFO: Tick 
2018-03-18 15:43:40.7914 - ERROR: Tock
```

file:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
  grok {      
      match => { 
            "message" => "(?m)^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}~~\[%{DATA:thread}\]~~\[%{DATA:user}\]~~\[%{DATA:requestId}\]~~\[%{DATA:userHost}\]~~\[%{DATA:requestUrl}\]~~%{DATA:level}~~%{DATA:logger}~~%{DATA:logmessage}~~%{DATA:exception}\|\|"
        }
      match => {
        "levell" => "(?m)^%{DATA:level}"
      }
      add_field => { 
        "received_at" => "%{@timestamp}" 
        "received_from" => "%{host}"
        "level" => "levell"
      }
      remove_field => ["message"]      
    }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" ]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    sniffing => true
    index => "filebeat-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

this prints out "levell" instead of "INFO/ERROR" etc

EDIT:
Input:

```
2018-03-18 15:43:40.7914 - INFO: Tick
```

configuration:

```
# Sample Logstash configuration for creating a simple
# Beats -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch pipeline.

input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
  grok {      
      match => { "message" => "(?m)^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}~~\[%{DATA:thread}\]~~\[%{DATA:user}\]~~\[%{DATA:requestId}\]~~\[%{DATA:userHost}\]~~\[%{DATA:requestUrl}\]~~%{DATA:level}~~%{DATA:logger}~~%{DATA:logmessage}~~%{DATA:exception}\|\|" }
      add_field => { 
        "received_at" => "%{@timestamp}" 
        "received_from" => "%{host}"
      } 
    }
  grok {      
      match => { "message" => "- %{LOGLEVEL:level}" }
      remove_field => ["message"]      
    }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS" ]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    sniffing => true
    index => "filebeat-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
    #user => "elastic"
    #password => "changeme"
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Output I'm getting. Still missing received_at and level:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that part of the configuration:

```
  add_field => { 
    "received_at" => "%{@timestamp}" 
    "received_from" => "%{host}"
    "level" => "levell"
  }
```

When using `"level" => "levell"`, you just put the String `levell` in the field `level`. To put the value of the field named `levell`, you have to use `%{levell}`. So in you case, it would look like:

```
  add_field => { 
    "received_at" => "%{@timestamp}" 
    "received_from" => "%{host}"
    "level" => "%{levell}"
  }
```

Also the `grok#match`, according to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_tag):

> A hash that defines the mapping of where to look, and with which patterns.

So trying to match on the `levell` field won't work, since it look like it doesn't exist yet. And the grok pattern you're using to match the `message` field don't match the example you provided.

Comment: So should it be this then? level" => "%{DATA:level}"

Comment: In which filter? If it's for a grok filter, the key (`level` in the comment you've posted) is the name of the field; the field has to exist before being used in the filter.

Comment: So how do i make it work so that "ERROR" in this line: 2018-03-18 15:43:40.7914 - ERROR: Tock, is stored into level?

Comment: `grok { match => { "message" => "- %{LOGLEVEL:level}" }}`

Comment: can you please see "EDIT", still can not make this work, and now "received_at" and "received_from" are missing. And I still do not see "level" :(. Can you please help

Comment: Do you realize that `add_field => { 
        "level" => "%{message}" 
      }` will erase the value of the field level you've just found in the grok pattern?

Comment: Also you are removing the field message in the first grok filter (` remove_field => ["message"]`), which would prevent you from using it to retrieve the level in the next grok filter.

Comment: baudsp, can you please see my EDIT. I'm still missing those fields. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: For the level field, the log in your picture looks nothing like the logs you provided as example, so it's normal that it doesn't work. With those logs, the pattern for the level would be like `\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:level}`

Comment: And for received_at, since the grok filter fails to parse the log (because your pattern don't fit the log), the  `add_field` isn't done.